# What options exist to create a shell app for iPhones that redirect to a website?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4, app-store

I have a client that needed to abandon their very poor native app and needs a temporary solution immediately. They have a mobile optimized website and we'd like to deploy an app in the store to replace the current one, and design it such that as soon as you launch it, it either hosts the site within a web browser control, or just redirects the user to a website in the iPhone Safari app. I realize there are subtle differences between the browser control and the actual Safari browsers.

Are there any tools or products that auto create such simple apps, and are there any problems with getting such simple apps approved by Apple?

Comment: You almost certainly won't pass review with something that just redirects someone to the website in Safari. You might or might not with something that wraps the web site… officially an app needs to do more than that, but sometimes such things can get through.

Comment: @AmyWorrall is correct. Apple is unlikely to approve such a thing.

Comment: Is it possible Apple would permit it as a temporary solution given the predicament they find themselves in? They paid a lot for a poorly functioning app, and are concerned about damaging their user's experience and losing their presence. Would apple possible allow an app like this temporarily until a replacement is found? How would you go about discussing this with Apple?

Comment: You could try emailing appreview@apple.com but I wouldn't hold out much hope. Is there any small bit of functionality you could add that would make it more than a web wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to make a **hybrid** app.

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/posts/a-primer-on-hybrid-apps-for-ios

Your app could just be a `UIWebView` that shows the website. It's possible that Apple might reject ithe app if there is nothing to it except a web view -- do some research on that possibility.